# What is happening in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the last of month, and in order to that i have written the following, to calculate the no. of days between today and the last date.

```
    select datediff(DAY,GETDATE(),dateadd(m,1,getdate()))-GETDATE()
```

the **bold** part gives me the no. of days between today and a month from today, say 30 or 31. and then I am subtracting today's date from 30 or 31, which is " -getdate() "

The output for the above query is

**1786-06-06 11:44:30.540**

Could you please explain what is happening in the query? I am not looking for a solution, I would like to know how is SQL-Server interpreting the query.

Thanks. :)

Comment: compare the outputs for "select 30 - GETDATE()" and "select 31 - GETDATE()".  I guess it converts 30 / 31 into a date somehow, looking at the difference between the two should show how

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bold part of the expressions does not return a date, it returns a number of days:

```
31
```

Convert that to a datetime:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 31);
```

This is 31 days *after* day 0 (`1900-01-01`):

```
1900-02-01
```

Now, subtract `GETDATE()` as an integer (`41512` days after day 0):

```
SELECT 31 - 41512 = -41481
```

Now add -41481 days to day 0:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -41481, 0);
-- or
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -41481, '19000101');
```

Or:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 31 - CONVERT(INT, GETDATE()));
```

Now, I strongly recommend a couple of things:

1. Don't use implicit date math. `@date_var_or_col - 1` for example fails with new data types like `DATE` and `DATETIME2`.
2. Don't use shorthand like `m`. If you mean `MONTH`, just take the massive productivity hit and type out `MONTH`. To see why, tell me if this provides the results you expect:

   ```
   SELECT DATEPART(y, GETDATE()), DATEPART(w, GETDATE());
   ```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, for the input. Guess i need to re-think how i write the rest of the query. 
But for now could you please take a look at this and let me know if correct. I did get the right output, but will this work for the entire calendar?

--TO GET LAST OF MONTH.
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE()))-(DATEPART(DD,GETDATE())), GETDATE())
  as Last_Of_Month;

Comment: @TanmoyDB first can you explain why you need the last day of the month? For most reporting queries, you want >= first of month and < first day of next month.

Comment: I am new to SQL and trying to write queries, for myself. So i am try to write them myself rather than searching for it online.

Comment: I get that, but understanding what you need to do with the last day of the month can help me guide you. You did ask for help, right? :-)

Comment: Yes, I need all the help I can get.
I came across a posting, which had First of, week, next week, month, next/previous etc.
So I am try some other variations on my own.

Comment: @TanmoyDB SQL Server 2012 introduced `EOMONTH()` but I find this pretty useless. If you have a datetime column and you want a monthly report, you can't say `BETWEEN first of month and EOMONTH` because `EOMONTH` returns the last day of the month at midnight. This means your report would be missing 23 hours and 59+ minutes of data.

Comment: last day of the month would have be 
08/31/2013 23:59:59 and not just the date.

Similarly First of week/month should also include the time portion as 00:00:00

Comment: @TanmoyDB but you could have datetime data at 23:59:59.997, datetime2 data at 23:59:59.9999999 so you could miss data, and if you are using smalldatetime it will round up and potentially include data from the next day. There is no perfect "end of the month" but < first of next month *always* works regardless of data type. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: OK, that's a good point to remember. Thanks for this.
This helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> I am subtracting today's date from 30 or 31, which is " -getdate() "

Sounds like you understand exactly what is happening, but maybe don't understand the results.

You are implicitly converting `GETDATE()` to a number, which represents the number of days (and fractional days) since `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM`

When you "subtract" `GETDATE()` (41,511 as of 8/27/2013) from `30` or `31` you get an answer of -41,480, or 41,480 days *before* `1/1/1900`, which would be about `6/6/1786` (plus or minus a few hours for the fractional part).